# Javascript Inner HTML with HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project for school and I wanted to create a javscript function which adds text to a html element with an onclick method which will run a function.

```
function a(func, words){
    var initfunc = "<span class = 'link' onclick='" + String(func) +"();'>" + 
            words + "</span>";
    return t.innerHTML += initfunc;
}
```

The issue is that when the page is ran with this function, the html presented has the tags acting as part of the string, not acting as html tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String(func)` won't give the name of the function.

For that, you can use [`func.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), defined in ES6 draft, but it will only work if the function is global.

Better use DOM methods if you want to add event listeners:

```
function a(func, words){
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'link';
    span.onclick = func;
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words));
    t.appendChild(span);
}
```